# Filter order by order status

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I am creating a custom dashboard for delivery guys where I want to show the order list in two divs. One is Pending Orders and second is History.
Basically I want to filter my order list by order status.
Here is code:

```
{% set pastOrders = craft.commerce.orders.relatedTo({targetElement: currentUser, field: 'deliveryGuy'}).find() %}
{% for order in pastOrders %}
   {{order.id}}
   {{order.orderStatus.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would run two queries and then you could utilise the `completed()` parameter:
https://craftcommerce.com/docs/craft-commerce-orders#completed

```
{% set pastOrders = craft.commerce.orders.completed(true).relatedTo({targetElement: currentUser, field: 'deliveryGuy'}).find() %}
{% for order in pastOrders %}
   {{order.id}}
   {{order.orderStatus.name}}
{% endfor %}

{% set pendingOrders = craft.commerce.orders.completed(false).relatedTo({targetElement: currentUser, field: 'deliveryGuy'}).find() %}
{% for order in pendingOrders %}
   {{order.id}}
   {{order.orderStatus.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Good solution by Luke,

But if you are still looking for a query to filter Orders by statuses, here's a working solution :

```
{% for pastOrders in craft.commerce.orders.customer(craft.commerce.customer).orderStatus(1).find() %}
    {{order.id}}
    {{order.orderStatus.name}}
{% endfor %}

{% for pendingOrders in craft.commerce.orders.customer(craft.commerce.customer).orderStatus(2).find() %}
    {{order.id}}
    {{order.orderStatus.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

Where 1 is the ID of your pasts orders and 2 is the ID of pending order status...